# Xpages only passes first character to Agent

Tags: xpages, lotusscript

I have created an Xpage to allow the administrator to input a single Notes Document (They are Contracts) ID into an edit box and press a button to delete the Contract.  The delete calls an Agent passing the Contract ID.  Below is the button script and then the relevant part of the Agent.  What is happening is only the first character is being passed to the Agent, i.e if the Contract ID is 9MXCB4 only "9" is being passed as the Agent message box prints this to the log. What am I doing wrong here?  If I hard code a Contract ID after the message box the Contract is processed correctly.

Button code

```
ag = database.getAgent("DeleteOneContract"); 
noteid = getComponent("ContractIDDelete").getValue()
ag.run(noteid)
```

Part of Agent code

```
Dim runAgent As NotesAgent
Dim deleteID As Variant

deleteID = runAgent.Parameterdocid 
MsgBox "Input is " & deleteID
'If line below is uncommented it processes the Contract correctly
'deleteID = "9MXCB4"
' Rest of agent process
....
```

Note that I have also tried runAgent.Target and runAgent.Query

Comment: To get things even more complicated - you can encode your contract id to valid hex value :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an extra thought on Jesse's and Mark's correct answers: from AJF's question we cannot tell whether the Xpage is bound to an actual NotesDocument object, or whether it is a (temporary) stand-alone page. In that case, of course, *agent.runWithDocumentContext* won't work.
But unless you have a good reason to perform the rest of your task using a LotusScript coding: why use an agent in the first place? Why not perform the deletion directly using SSJS code? On the Xpages side of the process you most probably will have to start with SSJS code very similar to Mark's example, but then why not go ahead and finish it off with two or three more lines?
In fact I try to avoid calling agents *directly* from my Xpages driven applications, due to performance issues, and because I don't like my code to be scattered all over the place.

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes you are correct and perhaps I wasn't clear in my question. There is NO Document open or selected when I attempt to pass the Contract ID to the Agent.  Maybe I should re-think as you say and instead of using an agent retrieve the document in an Xpages view and have the delete button deal with it there.

Comment: Glad if I could add a different option. When it comes to Xpages development it's always a good idea to step back and try to forget all those mechanisms, tricks and habits we need for legacy Notes client development, at leasst for the moment. Not always easy, but it helps. - And don't forget to accept one of the answers please.

Comment: Thanks again.  I have amened the page to have a dynamic view panel and bund this to a view.  What I am struggling with is getting the text from an edit box as a parameter to the dynamic view panel when I click a button

Comment: just a quick idea: maybe you can bind the editbox to some scope variable, and do the same with your view panel. Then have the button or whatever perform a partial refresh.

Answer (score 5):

Just tested that and when I pass it a valid NoteID, the agent reads it just fine. I don't think you can pass any other value than a NoteID to the agent this way.

An alternative might be to use the `agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc)` method and retrieve the document before sending it to the agent.

Comment: I thought the ContractID and the NoteID would be the same thing.  Is there a difference and can I obtain it in the button script?

Comment: Every document ('note') in a Notes database always has at least a UNID and NoteID. The UNID is a 32-character combination of hex digits (0-9, A-F) that uniquely identifies a document across all replicas, the NoteID is a hex value of (up to) 8 characters that uniquely identifies a document within a particular database. Your ContractID is probably a value created by your system and stored in a field. To retrieve the document for a ContractID you'll need to perform a search or view lookup in your database. And yes: you can do that in the button script.

Comment: Create a view that's sorted on ContractID, then in the button script open the view and retrieve the document: `var contractId = getComponent("ContractIDDelete").getValue(); var vw = database.getView('your_view'); var doc = vw.getDocumentByKey( contractId, true); var noteId = doc.getNoteID();`

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the note ID parameter has to actually be a hexidecimal number in string form. It doesn't have to line up with an actual note ID in the database, but it can only contain 0-9 and A-F (with presumably a cap on size).

Comment: We need 'question locking' on this site, so that I don't have to bother if someone's already answering a question. Or I should just type/test faster :-)

Comment: Or a 'merge answers' feature, since both you and Jesse gave good information that together provide a pretty complete answer.

Comment: @Jesse: are you sure about that? I remember that in my early days of Xpages dev I tried to pass a DocumentUniqueID (which is a hex value as well), and it didn't work while NoteIDs always did. This might be due to the fact that UNIDs are just too long, or it might have been an early-version issue (that was V 8.5 or 8.5.1 back then), and I never tried again, so my conclusions may be wrong

Comment: My hunch (without extensive testing) is that the API internally converts the string into a NOTEID, a 32-bit integer, so a UNID would overflow and fail. So the restriction presumably is "hex number from 00000000 to FFFFFFFF".